# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'setCenter')

Tags: reactjs, react-google-maps, react-google-maps-api

I am using react-google-maps-api. Before that approach I tried to use a state to change center but google maps didn't see the initial state. Then I found this approach below on github.

```
const [map, setMap] = React.useState(null)


useEffect(() => {
 country = hotels.find(h => h.country === choice);
 map.setCenter(hotels.find(h => h.country === choice)?.center);
 if (budgetValue == null) {
  filteredFlights = country.hotels
 } else {
  filteredFlights = country?.hotels.filter(f => f.price * personCount < budgetValue);
 }
 setMarkers(filteredFlights);
 }, [budgetValue]);
 
 const onLoad = React.useCallback(function callback(map) {

  setMap(map)
  }, [])

 const onUnmount = React.useCallback(function callback(map) {
  setMap(null)
 }, [])

return isLoaded ? (
 <GoogleMap
   mapContainerStyle={containerStyle}
   center={tempCenter}
   zoom={6}
   onLoad={(map) => {
    setMap(map);
   }}
onUnmount={onUnmount}
 >
{markers?.map((hotel, i) => {
  return showMarker !== i ?
    <Marker
      onLoad={onLoad}
      position={{ lat: hotel.lat, lng: hotel.lng }}
      onMouseOver={() => setShowMarker(i)}
      key={i}
    /> :
    <InfoWindowF
      onLoad={onLoad}
      position={{ lat: hotel.lat, lng: hotel.lng }}
      key={i}
    >
      <a href={hotel.url} target="_blank">
        <div onMouseOver={() => setShowMarker(i)} onMouseOut={() => setShowMarker(null)} style={divStyle}>
          <h1>{hotel.name}</h1>
          <img style={{ width: "200px", height: "100px" }} src={hotel.img} alt={hotel.name}></img>
          <Typography>
            Gecelik: {hotel.price}TL - {personCount} kişi: {hotel.price * personCount}TL
          </Typography>
        </div>
      </a>
    </InfoWindowF>
})}
<></>
</GoogleMap>
 ) : <></>
}
```

Trying to use map.setCenter() in useEffect but I get TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'setCenter'). Which I trying to achieve changing the center after useEffect runs. Thanks

Comment: The error is self-explanatory, you init map as null and then you are trying to modify it without null checking.

Comment: map is null when you call the .setCenter method. Make sure that is initialized before to use it.